# Javascript reload() not working

Tags: javascript, function, reload

I searched everywhere here to see since so many people ask this question, but no matter what, I keep getting `undefined`..

```
function remove_item(itemid) {
    var window = top.location;
    var host = window.host;

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://"+host+"/backend/remove_lockbox.php?id="+itemid,
        success: function() {
            $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
                window.top.location.reload();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

That is my code. I tried `window.location.reload`, `host.location.reload`... I tried everything and I keep getting `undefined`... The parent of location is always `undefined` whether it's `window`, `host`, `window.top`, ANYTHING.
Can someone PLEASE help me?

Comment: Nothing wrong with `window.top.location.reload();`, but really? `var window = top.location;`? It does not seem right.

Comment: another way window.top.location = window.top.location

Comment: use `document.location = document.location`

Comment: If there is nothing wrong with it, then why is it not working? I'm using Chrome... And why would I have to do window.top.location = window.top.location first?? If that value is already that value.. x_x

Comment: What is "undefined"? HUH? You should not be using a variable named window!

Comment: Derek was right. I had to erase the window = variable i set in the very beginning.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So you are doing

```
 var window = top.location;
```

and than you do

```
 window.top.location.reload();
```

So you are actually saying

```
top.location.top.location.reload();
```

Why would you use a variable named window when that is already defined and has a different meaning? That is bad.

If you are using frames I would expect to see something like

```
parent.location.reload(true);
```

or just a plain old window

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: You can not override `window`, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

try it this way, its working fine in chrome, as I know this should work fine in all modern browsers.

```
function remove_item(itemid) {

    var host = window.location.host;

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://"+host+"/backend/remove_lockbox.php?id="+itemid,
        success: function() {
            $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
                window.location.reload();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the working example of `window.location`, `window.location.host` and `window.location.reload`.

http://jsbin.com/apemen/3